# Django 2 Reference multiple users into one Model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2) in which I have multiple models using the `User` model. I have a gig model, A gig can be created by a user and another user user can buy this gig, so I want to build a model to store the purchase information in which I want to include the `Gig Model` and the `user` who has created the `Gig` as `seller` and the `user` who is buying the gig as `buyer` in the model. How can I create a model like that?

Here my `Gig` Model:

```
class Gig(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('GD', 'Graphic & Design'),
        ('DM', 'Digital Marketing'),
        ('WT', 'Writing & Translation'),
        ('VA', 'Video & Animation'),
        ('MA', 'Music & Audio'),
        ('PT', 'Programming & Tech'),
        ('FL', 'Fun & Lifestyle'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='gigs')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And here, what I want to achieve something like:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = "I want to add the gig creator here"
    buyer = "I want to add thee gig buyer here"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="selling")
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="buying")
```

Please make sure to have different `related_names` for each FK to User model, else they will conflict.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    gig = models.ForeignKey(Gig, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sold_orders')
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bought_orders')
```

P.S. Just a note that it's much better to use string model representation on ForeightKey fields in order to avoid possible circular import issue.
like:

```
gig = models.ForeignKey('Gig', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```